# Get current location with fused Location Provider

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-api

I have this Activity want to get current location but didn't now how to complete it in right way..also what is REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS??
do I have to generate one?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private TextView latitudeText, longitudeText;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        latitudeText = findViewById(R.id.latitudeText);
        longitudeText = findViewById(R.id.longitudeText);



        getLocation();

    }

    private void getLocation() {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setInterval(2000).setFastestInterval(2000).setPriority(1000);


        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {

                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    latitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                    longitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));



                }
            }
        };


        task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {


            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest
                    .permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

        } else if(){

        }






        }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

.....................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 4):

**Add dependency in build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

**Declare Necessary Permission in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**EasyLocationProvider.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCanceledListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

public class EasyLocationProvider implements LifecycleObserver {

    private EasyLocationCallback callback;
    private Context context;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private long interval;
    private long fastestInterval;
    private int priority;
    private double Latitude = 0.0, Longitude = 0.0;

    private EasyLocationProvider(final Builder builder) {
        context = builder.context;
        callback = builder.callback;
        interval = builder.interval;
        fastestInterval = builder.fastestInterval;
        priority = builder.priority;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void requestLocationUpdate() {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    private void connectGoogleClient() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE = 988;
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog((AppCompatActivity) context, resultCode, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    private void onCreateLocationProvider() {

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    private void onLocationResume() {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "Connected");

                        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                        mLocationRequest.setInterval(interval);
                        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);
                        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
                        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);

                        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
                        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
                        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
                        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

                        mSettingsClient
                                .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                                        showLog("GPS is Enabled Requested Location Update");
                                        requestLocationUpdate();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                                switch (statusCode) {
                                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                        try {
                                            int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 214;
                                            ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                            rae.startResolutionForResult((AppCompatActivity) context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                            showLog("Unable to Execute Request");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                        showLog("Location Settings are Inadequate, and Cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings");
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCanceled() {
                                showLog("onCanceled");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        connectGoogleClient();
                        callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "Connection Suspended");
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "" + connectionResult.getErrorCode() + " " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                })
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        connectGoogleClient();

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(final LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                Latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                Longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

                if (Latitude == 0.0 && Longitude == 0.0) {
                    showLog("New Location Requested");
                    requestLocationUpdate();
                } else {
                    callback.onLocationUpdated(Latitude, Longitude);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void removeUpdates() {
        try {
            callback.onLocationUpdateRemoved();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showLog(String message) {
        Log.e("EasyLocationProvider", "" + message);
    }

    public interface EasyLocationCallback {
        void onGoogleAPIClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String message);

        void onLocationUpdated(double latitude, double longitude);

        void onLocationUpdateRemoved();
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Context context;
        private EasyLocationCallback callback;
        private long interval = 10 * 1000;
        private long fastestInterval = 5 * 1000;
        private int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;

        public Builder(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public EasyLocationProvider build() {
            if (callback == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "EasyLocationCallback listener can not be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return new EasyLocationProvider(this);
        }

        public Builder setListener(EasyLocationCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setInterval(long interval) {
            this.interval = interval;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setFastestInterval(int fastestInterval) {
            this.fastestInterval = fastestInterval;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPriority(int priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
EasyLocationProvider easyLocationProvider; //Declare Global Variable

easyLocationProvider = new EasyLocationProvider.Builder(BottomNavigationActivity.this)
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(2000)
                //.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setListener(new EasyLocationProvider.EasyLocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGoogleAPIClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String message) {
                        Log.e("EasyLocationProvider","onGoogleAPIClient: "+message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationUpdated(double latitude, double longitude) {
                        Log.e("EasyLocationProvider","onLocationUpdated:: "+ "Latitude: "+latitude+" Longitude: "+longitude);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationUpdateRemoved() {
                        Log.e("EasyLocationProvider","onLocationUpdateRemoved");
                    }
                }).build();

getLifecycle().addObserver(easyLocationProvider);
```

**Remove Location Update Callback**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    easyLocationProvider.removeUpdates();
    getLifecycle().removeObserver(easyLocationProvider);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**NOTE: Grant Permissions for Marshmallow and Above Version Devices**

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getLocation();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So it's up to you to define `REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS` and it's role is to handle the callback, especially if you ask for more than on permission.

And I think your `getLocation()` uses a deprecated API. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) on how to get the location.

Answer (score 0):

Ketan Ramani's answer helped me and all credits to him. I made a little adjustment to be able to set the number of updates especially in the event one is only required.

```
public class LocationProvider implements LifecycleObserver {

private EasyLocationCallback callback;
private Context context;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
private long interval;
private long fastestInterval;
private int priority;
private int numberOfUpdates;
private double Latitude = 0.0, Longitude = 0.0;

private LocationProvider(final Builder builder) {
    context = builder.context;
    callback = builder.callback;
    interval = builder.interval;
    fastestInterval = builder.fastestInterval;
    priority = builder.priority;
    numberOfUpdates = builder.numberOfUpdates;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void requestLocationUpdate() {
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
}

private void connectGoogleClient() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE = 988;
        googleAPI.getErrorDialog((AppCompatActivity) context, resultCode, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICE);
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
private void onCreateLocationProvider() {

}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
private void onLocationResume() {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                    callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "Connected");

                    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    mLocationRequest.setInterval(interval);
                    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestInterval);
                    mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
                    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
                    if (numberOfUpdates > 0) mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(numberOfUpdates);

                    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
                    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
                    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
                    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

                    mSettingsClient
                            .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> {
                                showLog("GPS is Enabled Requested Location Update");
                                requestLocationUpdate();
                            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                                switch (statusCode) {
                                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                        try {
                                            int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 214;
                                            ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                            rae.startResolutionForResult((AppCompatActivity) context, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                            showLog("Unable to Execute Request");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                        showLog("Location Settings are Inadequate, and Cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings");
                                }
                            }).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCanceled() {
                            showLog("onCanceled");
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    connectGoogleClient();
                    callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "Connection Suspended");
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    callback.onGoogleAPIClient(mGoogleApiClient, "" + connectionResult.getErrorCode() + " " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                }
            })
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    connectGoogleClient();

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(final LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

            Latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
            Longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

            if (Latitude == 0.0 && Longitude == 0.0) {
                showLog("New Location Requested");
                requestLocationUpdate();
            } else {
                callback.onLocationUpdated(Latitude, Longitude);
            }
        }
    };
}

public LatLng getLastLocation() {
    if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        Location location = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().getResult();
        return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void removeUpdates() {
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        callback.onLocationUpdateRemoved();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showLog(String message) {
    Log.e("LocationProvider", "" + message);
}

public interface EasyLocationCallback {
    void onGoogleAPIClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String message);

    void onLocationUpdated(double latitude, double longitude);

    void onLocationUpdateRemoved();
}

public static class Builder {
    private Context context;
    private EasyLocationCallback callback;
    private long interval = 10 * 1000;
    private long fastestInterval = 5 * 1000;
    private int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
    private int numberOfUpdates = 0;

    public Builder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public LocationProvider build() {
        if (callback == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "EasyLocationCallback listener can not be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return new LocationProvider(this);
    }

    public Builder setListener(EasyLocationCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setInterval(long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setFastestInterval(int fastestInterval) {
        this.fastestInterval = fastestInterval;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setNumberOfUpdates(int numberOfUpdates) {
        this.numberOfUpdates = numberOfUpdates;
        return this;
       }
   }
 }
```

**Setting the locationProvider**

```
  locationProvider = new LocationProvider.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setInterval(10000)
            .setFastestInterval(5000)
            .setNumberOfUpdates(1) // If you want infinite updates, remove this line entirely
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setListener(new LocationProvider.EasyLocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onGoogleAPIClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String message) {
                    Log.e("LocationProvider", "onGoogleAPIClient: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationUpdated(double updateLatitude, double updateLongitude) {
                    // You could also add some intelligence to remove the location listener once counter == numberOfUpdates

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationUpdateRemoved() {
                    Log.e("LocationProvider", "onLocationUpdateRemoved");
                }
            }).build();

    getLifecycle().addObserver(locationProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone is finding the solution for this. You can now use [FusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-tasklocation-getcurrentlocation-int-priority,-cancellationtoken-token) in play-services-location library version `17.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below way to get the location using the FusedLocationProviderClient

```
public class LocationTrackerClient{
    public static String TAG = LocationTrackerClient.class.getName();
    private Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    static Context mcontext;
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 5;

    private static LocationTrackerClient instance;
    private boolean isConnected = false;

    public static synchronized LocationTrackerClient getInstance(Context ctx) {

        mcontext = ctx;
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LocationTrackerClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void getLocationclient() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient = null;
            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mcontext);

            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

    public void connectToLocation() {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        getLocationclient();
        displayLocation();
    }


    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        removeFusedLocationUpdate();
    }

    public void removeFusedLocationUpdate() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            }else{
                return;
            }
        }

        try {
            if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                mFusedLocationClient
                        .removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Logger.d(TAG, "Location updates stopped at removeFusedLocationUpdate! == ");
//                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location updates stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);

        }
    }

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            Logger.e(TAG, "locationResult ==== " + locationResult);
            if (locationResult != null) {
                mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                if (mLastLocation != null) {
                    double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                    updateLattitudeLongitude(latitude, longitude);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void updateLattitudeLongitude(double latitude, double longitude) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "updated Lat == " + latitude + "  updated long == " + longitude);
        SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance();
        sharedPreferenceManager.updateUserDeviceLatLong(latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```