# Android GPS location not accurate

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

I am having an issue with an Android app I am developing.  The application runs a countdown timer and sends a text message when the timer reaches zero.  At 9 seconds, The application is supposed to get the location of the phone. When the timer reaches zero, it sends the location (received at 9 seconds) as a maplink in the text message.

The application works, but the GPS location it sends is sometimes over 100 meters away.  I need the application to be as precise as possible.  I have a version using the android.location framework and a version using the fusedlocationapi.  The android.location version I have is far more accurate than the fusedlocationapi which is very confusing to me.

The thing that really bothers me is the following: If I run the timer and get an inaccurate location, I can open google maps (which will show a very accurate location), go back to my app, run the timer again and I will receive a precise location (similar to what google maps just showed me).  Is google maps using a better method to get my location or is my code just bad?  I thought the app would show the same location as google maps but it is not and this is frustrating me a great deal.  Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code where I add the fusedlocationapi:

```
  /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location requests here
                        getLocation();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(SafetyAlarmActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        getLocation();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, " mGoogleApiClient Connection connected:");

        getLocation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "+ connectionResult.getErrorCode());


    }
```

Here is the code where the app gets the location at 9 seconds:

```
    /*
    update GPS location
     */

    private void updateGPSLocation(long millisUntilFinished) {

        Log.e("current time remaining", " time: "+millisUntilFinished/1000);


        if(millisUntilFinished/1000==9)
        {

            Log.e("9 seconds remaining", "get locaiton");

            getLocation();
        }
    }

     /*
  get location
   */

    private void getLocation()
    {

        try
        {
            Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            PersistObject.apply(con,AppConstant.LOCATION,lastLocation);

        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Here are my permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: please set                 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
Note: LocationRequest mLocationRequest.

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348535/6667442

Comment: He use PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY as you (Avinash Ajay Pandey) can see in his code. I suggest you to use actual location api -  FusedLocationProviderClient. In your code you try to get last location, what will be if device don't has it?

Comment: take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276698/android-my-app-can-get-location-information-until-opening-google-maps-although/53276863#53276863 , and what is your permission that you ask?

Comment: @VadimEksler I edited the post to show my permissions.

Comment: and what about     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @VadimEksler Sorry, those are in there as well.  I was just having trouble adding them to this question.

Comment: did you tried to use FusedLocationProviderClient without GoogleApiClient?

Comment: **getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)** this will give last known location. so if you want update after that you have to register for updates then only you will get updated location.